# How can you compute the number of topological sorts in a DAG?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs, sorting

If you have a [directed acyclic graph (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) $G$, a topological sort is just an ordering of the vertices such that if an edge $x \to y$ exists in $G$, then the index of $x$ is less than the index of $y$.

It's not hard to figure out how a topological sort can be given, but how efficiently can one compute the total number of topological sorts that exist for a given acyclic graph?

Comment: Oops. I should have paid attention to the tag. I clicked on this expecting DAG to mean Derived Algebraic Geometry. :(

Comment: Me too. Is DAG a standard acronym in graph theory?

Comment: Dr Shello: yes, DAG is a very standard abbreviation. It is often spoken as well and is pronounced to rhyme with "bag".

Comment: Directed Acyclic Graph

Comment: Aye, Directed Acyclic Graph. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 13):

This problem is [#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete). See ["Counting linear extensions is #P-complete"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/103418.103441), G. Brightwell and P. Winkler, Proc. 23rd ACM Symposium on the Theory of Computing, 1991

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better answer. Thanks for the great reference.